# How to identify peaks and troughs in an array of floats?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array,

```
array = [
  0.43, 
  0.64, # => peak
  0.2, 
 -0.05, 
 -0.15, # => trough
  0.2, # => peak
 -0.1, 
 -0.5, # => trough
 -0.3
]
```

which has two peaks and two troughs in the data. These peaks and troughs are not necessarily the *min* and *max* of the array. How do I identify those by program?

The ideal output would be:

```
peak_indexes = [1, 5]
trough_indexes = [4, 7]
```

Comment: What makes -0.5 a negative peak?

Comment: @ElChapo because the data before it is closer to 0 than -0.5 is

Comment: So in that case would every final element be a peak/trough?. Peak if the element before it is closer to 0, Trough if the element before it is further from 0.

Comment: That's a reasonable point to make. I would say exclude the final element then as I suppose it cannot be determined if it is a true peak or not

Comment: This can be done using `inject` also

Comment: What if a peak / trough spans multiple elements, e.g. `[0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each_cons(3)` extracts adjacent three terms needed to examine the middle term while excluding the triplets with the first or the last element of `array` in the middle.

`with_index(1)` considers the fact that the triplet with the first element of `array` in the middle was skipped, thus numbering the indices starting from 1.

You have not defined what you mean by peaks and troughs. If you mean to take the local max and min, then the following will work.

```
array.each_cons(3).with_index(1).select{|a, i| a.max == a[1]}.map(&:last)
# => [1, 5]

array.each_cons(3).with_index(1).select{|a, i| a.min == a[1]}.map(&:last)
# => [4, 7]
```

Or, if you mean what Stefan explains in the comment to my answer, then the following will work:

```
array
.each_cons(3)
.with_index(1)
.select{|(a1, a2, a3), i| a1 < a2 && a2 > a3}
.map(&:last)
# => [1, 5]

array
.each_cons(3)
.with_index(1)
.select{|(a1, a2, a3), i| a1 > a2 && a2 < a3}
.map(&:last)
# => [4, 7]
```

Comment: `a.max == a[1]` / `a.min == a[1]` give false positives if there are multiple identical entries, e.g. `[0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3]`. You should instead check if the middle element is actually greater than (not greater than or equal to) its neighbors, e.g. via `|(a, b, c), i| a < b && b > c }`

Comment: Wish Ruby had chained comparisons like Python does. `a < b > c` would look so cool.

Comment: @Stefan I think that would make the syntax complicated. That expression would have to be understood as a single construction, not as successive application of two methods. I.e., `a < b> c` would not be meant to mean `(a < b) > c`. Some mathematical expressions are not suitable for programming. Another example is `$a, b \in A$`, which would perhaps be confused with multiple assignment if it were imported to Ruby.

Comment: `(a < b) > c` doesn't make much sense anyway, because `a < b` returns either `true` of `false`, neither of which responds to `>`. Unfortunately, `1 < 2 == true` would be evaluated differently, so this might break existing code. That aside, I think it's _very_ suitable for programming.

Answer (score 1):

First let's define what it means for something to be a peak or a trough.

- A peak is a value which is LARGER than the value on it's left & right.
- A trough is a value which is SMALLER than the value on it's left & right.

This will allow us to define two helpful functions:

```
def is_peak?(left_value, value, right_value)
  return value > left_value && value > right_value
end

def is_trough?(left_value, value, right_value)
  return value < left_value && value < right_value
end
```

Now we can go through each element in the array and use these functions to ask whether the element is a peak or a trough.

```
array = [0.43, 0.64, 0.2, -0.05, -0.15, 0.2, -0.1, -0.5]
positive_peak_indexes = []
negative_peak_indexes = []
# Loop through the array
array.each_with_index do |elem, i|
  # Make sure we don't get an out of bounds exception
  next if (i-1 < 0) || (i + 1 >= array.length)

  # Now we add to our appropriate arrays if it's a peak/trough
  positive_peak_indexes << i if is_peak?(array[i-1], elem, array[i+1])
  negative_peak_indexes << i if is_trough?(array[i-1], elem, array[i+1])
end
puts "positive_peak_indexes = #{positive_peak_indexes.to_s}"
puts "negative_peak_indexes = #{negative_peak_indexes.to_s}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not had the time to test on more cases, so maybe there is some bug.

Anyway, the basic idea is to zip each element with it's index ([Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)), then use the method [Enumerable#chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) to slice the array when there is a change. Finally extract from the chunks the extremes.

Better with a piece of code, `ary` is the array of data.

First the chunks:

```
chunks = ary.map.with_index{ |x, i| [x,i] }.chunk_while { |x,y| y.first < x.first }
```

Then collect the extremes:

```
peaks = chunks.collect { |e| e.first if e.size > 1 }.compact #=> [[0.64, 1], [0.2, 5]]
trough = chunks.collect { |e| e.last if e.size > 1 }.compact #=> [[-0.15, 4], [-0.5, 7]]
```